# How can I obtain courseWorkId so I can set score from my app?

Tags: javascript, google-classroom

I use JavaScript to post a link from my website into a user's Google Classroom. Students click on the link from Classroom, authenticate to my site, then complete a test. The test is scored automatically and score saved at my site. I want to use JavaScript to set the score for this task in Google Classroom so they are synced.

I see that I need to get the courseWorkId to do this, but I do not yet know how.

How do I obtain the courseWorkId for a class in JavaScript so that I can then set its score using patch?

Comment: Try to use the [REST Resource: courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions) from there, it was stated that "*StudentSubmission items are generated when a CourseWork item is created*".

Comment: Great, thank you! Now I'm stuck on getting the particular studentCourseWorkId so I can change its score.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I get the coursework ids:

```
gapi.client.classroom.courses.courseWork.list({
  "courseId": id, // include the course id here
  "courseWorkStates": ["PUBLISHED"],
  "pageSize": "10"
})
  .then((res)=>{

    let courseWork = res.result.courseWork;

    courseWork.forEach(()=>{
      if (courseWork && courseWork.length > 0) {
        courseWork.forEach((assignment) => {
          //print assignment ids
          console.log(assigment.id)
        });
      }
    })
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried the "Try this API" section under reference https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/list

Comment: Yes, it works in "Try this API". I am not great with JSON parsing yet and cannot seem toquite get this work work to get thestudent's submission ID:

Comment: gapi.client.classroom.courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.list({
          courseId: gCourseId,
          courseWorkId: gCourseWorkId,
          userId:'stdEmail'
        }).then(function(response) {
        
        //var myObj = response.result.courseWork.studentSubmissions;
        //var x = myObj.id;
        //var y = myObj.draftGrade;

        //console.log(x); 
        //console.log(y); 

        console.log(
        
        });